# CoffeeScript+processing.js draw image fails

Tags: canvas, coffeescript, processing.js

I try to load image with processing.js using CoffeeScript and write this simple code:

```
canvas1_proc = (ps) -> 
    ps.setup = ->
        ps.noLoop()
        ps.size(550, 400)
        @img = ps.loadImage('1.png')
    ps.draw = ->
        ps.image(@img, 0, 0)

$(document).ready () ->
    canvas1 = document.getElementById 'canvas-1'
    processing = new Processing(canvas1, canvas1_proc)
```

CoffeeScript code is compiled into the code

```
var canvas1_proc;
canvas1_proc = function(ps) {
  ps.setup = function() {
    ps.noLoop();
    ps.size(550, 400);
    return this.img = ps.loadImage('1.png');
  };
  return ps.draw = function() {
    return ps.image(this.img, 0, 0);
  };
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  var canvas1, processing;
  canvas1 = document.getElementById('canvas-1');
  return processing = new Processing(canvas1, canvas1_proc);
});
```

The image is not displayed and no errors in js console. Where is my mistake?

Comment: What happens if you try doing something other than `loadImage`? For instance, what if you make the draw function `ps.background(ps.frameCount)`—do you get pulsing background colors, or nothing?

Comment: yes, ps.background(ps.frameCount) works fine

Comment: It is required to use the directive `@pjs preload` to load the image. This directive didn't work with coffeescript or js. I still have not found a way to load without this directive.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a preload issue?  I tried this, porting the halftone-dots code in the Processing.js examples to coffeescript, and it worked fine.

Comment: Yes, it preload issue. But preload directive works only on PJS and don't work on Coffee. The question is how to preload image without any directives, using only CoffeScript or JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David Humphrey's code, ported to Coffeescript.  Works like a charm:

```
canvas1_proc = (ps) ->
    ps.setup = () ->
        ps.noLoop()
        ps.size 550, 400
        this.img = ps.loadImage '1.png'

    ps.draw = () ->
        ps.image this.img, 0, 0

$(document).ready () ->
    sketch = new Processing.Sketch canvas1_proc
    sketch.imageCache.add '1.png'
    canvas1 = document.getElementById 'canvas-1'
    p = new Processing canvas1, sketch
```

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, this is asynchronous image loading vs. processing's synchronous image loading in loadImage.  You need to either use a Processing.Sketch object and preload your image using js, or skip frames in draw(), bailing early until @img.loaded is true.

What I'd do here is create a Processing.Sketch object, passing your code as a function.  This Sketch object can then be used to set various options, add images to the image cache, etc.  I don't know CoffeeScript, so here's the js way:

```
canvas1_proc = function(ps) {
  ps.setup = function() {
    ps.noLoop();
    ps.size(550, 400);
    return this.img = ps.loadImage('1.png');
  };
  return ps.draw = function() {
    return ps.image(this.img, 0, 0);
  };
};

var sketch = new Processing.Sketch(canvas1_proc);
sketch.imageCache.add('1.png'); // will kick off a load in the background
var p = new Processing(canvas, sketch); // will wait for imageCache to be ready
```

We wait to start sketches until the imageCache is empty, and then when you call loadImage() and the like, we first try to pull things out of that cache (keyed by the URL, 1.png in this case).

I'll file a bug to get this better documented.  In the mean time, here's the code for a Processing.Sketch object, which also includes access to all @pjs directives:

https://github.com/humphd/processing-js/blob/1.2/processing.js#L19328

Come chat with me on irc if you need more help (humph on irc.mozilla.org/processing.js), or on twitter @humphd.  Maybe you can help me write something specifically about using Processing.js with CoffeeScript, since so many people are doing it these days :)

Comment: Add image to cache before load canvas proc is a good idea, but this code didn't work. The `Processing.Sketch(canvas1_proc);` returns nothing, `sketch` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm not sure what the best practice is here, but here's the problem: The image is being loaded *after* it's being drawn. This is because loading in JS is async, and Processing only knows to wait until images are loaded if given an `@pjs` directive via a comment in the Processing code (which is treated separately from the compilation to JS in `Processing.compile`).

One fix is to use the callback to `ps.loadImage` (its third argument—the first two are the image name and type) to force a redraw. Change the line

```
@img = ps.loadImage('1.png')
```

to

```
@img = ps.loadImage '1', 'png', -> ps.draw()
```

That way, you'll get one initial `draw`, then another when the image is loaded.

Comment: this solution didn't work, because @img is not initialized, when callback is called

Comment: Works fine in my tests, using your exact code. Are you using Processing 1.1.0?